# Need advice with a Query to list Top 5 rated games

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Hi i am helping my friend create a website that shows ratings for games.

My table and columns are:

**Games**

- game_id
- title
- genre

**Ratings**

- user_id
- game_id
- rating
- timestamp

**Users**

- user_id
- gender
- age
- Occupation
- zip code

I would need help creating a SQL query that lists:

- Top 5 highest rated games per user gender
- Top 5 highest rated games per user age group
- Top 5 highest rated games per occupation

I have tried looking at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp but i am not good with SQL and could use some advice

Comment: Look into the `LIMIT` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of **INNER JOINS** to pull the data together:

```
SELECT g.title, g.genre, r.rating, u.gender
FROM rating r
INNER JOIN u.user_id on r.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN g.game_id on r.game_id = g.game_id
```

This data can then be sorted by using an **ORDER BY** clause to allow for the rating to be sorted accordingly:

```
SELECT g.title, g.genre, r.rating, u.gender
FROM rating r
INNER JOIN u.user_id on r.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN g.game_id on r.game_id = g.game_id
ORDER BY r.rating DESC;
```

In order to only return the top *number* of results, use the **LIMIT** *number* clause.

A complete example of this can be seen below:

```
SELECT g.title, g.genre, r.rating, u.gender
FROM rating r
INNER JOIN u.user_id on r.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN g.game_id on r.game_id = g.game_id
ORDER BY r.rating DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

This example tailors to the first SQL Query requirement that you listed - the other two queries can be achieved by following the same structure.

---

### EDIT :

After further understanding of the OP's original post, the complete example query above is adapted below. Since the requirement is to return the top 5 games based on their averaged ratings from users - the use of the clause **AVG()** must be used to obtain the averages of game ratings.

Whilst the use of the **GROUP BY** clause allows for each unique game_id to have it's average value calculated for it. Example of these clauses in use:

```
SELECT g.title, g.genre, AVG(r.rating), u.gender
FROM rating r
INNER JOIN u.user_id on r.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN g.game_id on r.game_id = g.game_id
GROUP BY g.game_id
ORDER BY AVG(r.rating) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: There is no `TOP` in postresql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for mentioning, I didn't notice that. I've adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: At first it seemed like this was what i needed :-) however i noticed that it only limits the ratings of 5 different users.

I think i need a count (*) so that it sums / averages the ratings per game


Because a game can recieve different ratings from different users so all the ratings for each game needs to be summed up :o

Comment: @Jessica No worries, I didn't quite understand that from your original post - I've edited the post above to hopefully tailor to what you are trying to achieve :)